# C: scanf and printf error during second prompt input

Tags: c, printf

The first half of this code runs with no issues. I can enter in the second set of char float int char input but not sure why my code displays zeros in display prompt.

```
/*Prompt the user and accept the following 4 types of values from a single 
input line: char int char float */
char ch1, ch2;
int num1;
float num2;
printf("Enter char int char float: ");
scanf("%c %d %c %f",&ch1, &num1, &ch2, &num2)   ;
printf("You entered: '%c' %d '%c' %.3f\n", ch1, num1, ch2, num2);


/*Prompt the user and accept the following types of values from a 
single input line: char float int char */
char ch3, ch4;
float num3;
int num4;
printf("Enter char float int char: ");
scanf("%c %f %d %c",&ch3, &num3, &num4, &ch4);
printf("You entered: '%c' %.3f %d '%c'\n", ch3, num3, num4, ch4);
```

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The space is the problem.

The first enter  `ENTER` you stroke is considered as  input for the second `scan`. Use a space like the following:

`scanf("`**[SPACEHERE]**`%c %f %d %c",&ch3, &num3, &num4, &ch4);`

[Here for more details](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()`. `getchar()` takes an unknown `char` form `stdin` .
use after first `prinf`.

```
printf("You entered: '%c' %d '%c' %.3f\n", ch1, num1, ch2, num2);

getchar();//add this
```

Comment: How did you find out that `You can use getchar() under the header #include<string.h>` ? are you sure that is **string.h**?

Comment: oh yes i see.. @Michi